# JMX Trans gives "Port already in use" but the port is free

Tags: jmx, jmxtrans

I'm trying to use jmxtrans to send metrics of Kafka to Influxdb. I've downloded the jar file and configured necessary files for my case. When I try to start the jmxtrans as `JAR_FILE=jmxtrans-259-all.jar jmxtrans.sh jvm.json` it gives the `Port already in use: 5555` error (5555 is the jmx port). My kafka systemd file (prometheus doesn't use jmx port):

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka Server (broker)
Documentation=http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html
Requires=kafka-zookeeper.service
After=network.target remote-fs.target kafka-zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafka
Group=confluent
WorkingDirectory=/etc/systemd/system/
ExecStart=/bin/bash /etc/systemd/system/kafka
Restart=always
Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/kafka/vty/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=7080:/kafka/vty/kafka-0-8-2.yml"
#Environment="JMX_PORT=5555"
Environment="KAFKA_JMX_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=isstdkafld01 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5555"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am pretty sure there is no process that uses the 5555 port, except kafka (PID 17397 is kafka). `netstat -nltp` also confirms that:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      124801/java         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2191            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      124801/java         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1184/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9072            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17397/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20048           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1637/rpc.mountd     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17397/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36629           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17397/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33429           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17397/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10716/sshd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43675           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45759           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1649/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34183           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      124801/java         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17397/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::9519                 :::*                    LISTEN      94054/nsrexecd      
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1184/rpcbind        
tcp6       0      0 :::20048                :::*                    LISTEN      1637/rpc.mountd     
tcp6       0      0 :::8370                 :::*                    LISTEN      94054/nsrexecd      
tcp6       0      0 :::8146                 :::*                    LISTEN      94054/nsrexecd      
tcp6       0      0 :::4118                 :::*                    LISTEN      28915/ds_agent      
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      20644/grafana-serve 
tcp6       0      0 :::7937                 :::*                    LISTEN      94054/nsrexecd      
tcp6       0      0 :::41537                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      123916/prometheus   
tcp6       0      0 :::7938                 :::*                    LISTEN      94054/nsrexecd      
tcp6       0      0 :::33443                :::*                    LISTEN      1649/rpc.statd
```

What could be the reason? Mind that when I try to use another port which is not the jmx port, it doesn't give this error and goes for a timeout. The files I use are given below.

jvm.json (8086 is the port for influxdb)

```
{
  "servers" : [ {
    "port" : "9072",
    "host" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "alias": "kafka-1",
    "queries" : [ {
      "outputWriters" : [
      {
        "@class" : "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
        "url" : "http://xxxxxxxxxx:8086/",
        "database" : "kafka",
        "username" : "admin",
        "password" : "admin"
      } ],
      "obj" : "java.lang:type=Memory",
      "attr" : [ "HeapMemoryUsage", "NonHeapMemoryUsage" ],
      "resultAlias" : "jvmMemory"
    }
    ],
    "numQueryThreads" : 1
  } ]
}
```

jmxtrans.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# The MIT License
# Copyright © 2010 JmxTrans team
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
# THE SOFTWARE.
#

if (( $# != 1 )); then
  echo "Usage: jmxtrans.sh <json file or dir>"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ -f "${1}" ]]; then
  JSON_CONFIG_OPT="-f ${1}"
elif [[ -d "${1}" ]]; then
  JSON_CONFIG_OPT="-j ${1}"
else
  echo "${1} is not a file nor a directory"
  exit 1
fi

JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME:-"/usr"}
LOG_DIR=${LOG_DIR:-"."}

if [[ "${JAR_FILE}" == "" ]]; then
  JAR_FILE="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/../lib" >/dev/null && pwd )/jmxtrans-all.jar"
fi
ADDITIONAL_JARS=${ADDITIONAL_JARS:-""}
SECONDS_BETWEEN_RUNS=${SECONDS_BETWEEN_RUNS:-"60"}

JAVA=${JAVA:-"${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"}
CHECK_JAVA=${CHECK_JAVA:-"true"}
JAVA_OPTS=${JAVA_OPTS:-"-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"}
HEAP_SIZE=${HEAP_SIZE:-"512"}
PERM_SIZE=${PERM_SIZE:-"384"}
MAX_PERM_SIZE=${MAX_PERM_SIZE:-"384"}
JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-"5555"}
LOG_LEVEL=${LOG_LEVEL:-"info"}
CONTINUE_ON_ERROR=${CONTINUE_ON_ERROR:-"false"}
JMXTRANS_OPTS="${JMXTRANS_OPTS} -Djmxtrans.log.level=${LOG_LEVEL} -Djmxtrans.log.dir=${LOG_DIR}"


MONITOR_OPTS=${MONITOR_OPTS:-"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=${JMX_PORT}"}
GC_OPTS=${GC_OPTS:-"-Xms${HEAP_SIZE}m -Xmx${HEAP_SIZE}m"}
SSL_OPTS=${SSL_OPTS:-""}
if [[ "${SSL_TRUSTSTORE}" != "" ]]; then
    SSL_OPTS="${SSL_OPTS} -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${SSL_TRUSTSTORE}"
    if [[ "${SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}" != "" ]]; then
        SSL_OPTS="${SSL_OPTS} -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}"
    fi
fi

if [[ "${ADDITIONAL_JARS}" == "" ]]; then
  ADDITIONAL_JARS_OPTS=""
else
  ADDITIONAL_JARS_OPTS="-a ${ADDITIONAL_JARS}"
fi

if [[ "${CHECK_JAVA}" == "true" ]]; then
    JAVA_VERSION=`${JAVA} -version 2>&1`
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        echo "Cannot execute ${JAVA}!"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

if [[ ! -f ${JAR_FILE} ]]; then
  echo "File not found - ${JAR_FILE}"
  exit 1
fi

EXEC=${EXEC:-"-jar ${JAR_FILE} -e ${JSON_CONFIG_OPT} -s ${SECONDS_BETWEEN_RUNS} -c ${CONTINUE_ON_ERROR} ${ADDITIONAL_JARS_OPTS} ${ADDITIONAL_OPTS}"}

${JAVA} -server ${JAVA_OPTS} ${JMXTRANS_OPTS} ${GC_OPTS} ${MONITOR_OPTS} ${SSL_OPTS} ${EXEC}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving the `JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-"5555"}` line in `jmxtrans.sh` as its default value, `2101` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Address already use issue:

Open your terminal:

```
ps aux || grep
```

list all running services and find the id you want to kill.

```
sudo kill -9 <id you want to kill>
```

Comment: but there is not a process that uses the 5555 port. also when I type the command as" | grep 5555" it gives the same output

Comment: In which editor you will work, you will learn and obtain the identity of that editor. you are buying this place to run the port from another place, to pick up and train you from another place.